# Error initializing PDF reDirect ProFinding to merge two files

Tags: ms-access, pdf, merge, vba

I've found this code that should find two matching pdf-filenames and merges them into 1 pdf-file always in the same order. File 1 then File 2.

The code matches filenames based on the first part of the filename, before the AnotherWord 2014.pdf or before SomeWord.pdf.

- Example document name1: John Doe SomeWord.pdf
- Example document name2:   John Doe AnotherWord 2014.pdf

I use **PDF reDirect Pro v2.5.2 (freeware)** and a reference to the program.

The problem I have is that the line

`Dim oPDF As New PDF_reDirect_v25002.Batch_RC_AXD`

That gives me the error:

> User-defined type not defined

How can I fix this?

This is the whole code:

```
    Private Sub Knop0_Click()

'Only works with PDF reDirect Pro v2.5.2
'And needs to have a reference to PDF_reDirect_v2500 and PDF reDirect Pro Remote Control
Dim fs As Object
Dim fld As Object
Dim fld2 As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim objFile2 As Object
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oPDF As New PDF_reDirect_v25002.Batch_RC_AXD
Dim TempBool As Boolean
Dim Files_to_Merge(1) As String
Dim ObjFileName() As String
Dim CellNameValue() As String
Dim ofn As String
Dim cnv As String
Dim i As Integer

Set fld = fs.GetFolder("C:\pdf")
Set fld2 = fs.GetFolder("C:\pdf\merged")
i = 1

For Each objFile In fld.files
For Each objFile2 In fld.files
    CellNameValue() = Split(objFile.Name, " SomeWord.pdf")
    cnv = CellNameValue(0)
    ObjFileName() = Split(objFile2.Name, " AnotherWord 2014.pdf")
    ofn = ObjFileName(0)
    Files_to_Merge(1) = fld & "\" & ofn & " AnotherWord 2014.pdf"
    Files_to_Merge(0) = fld & "\" & cnv & " SomeWord.pdf"
    If StrComp(ofn, cnv) = 0 Then
    With oPDF

        TempBool = .Utility_Merge_PDF_Files(fld2 & "\" & ofn & " AnotherWord 2014.pdf", Files_to_Merge) 'The file merges here unless it generates an error and goes to If Not TempBool Then...

        If Not TempBool Then
            MsgBox "An Error Occured: etc."
        Else
            'Optional
        End If
    End With
    End If
    i = i + 1
    Next objFile2
     i = i + 1
    Next objFile
    Set oPDF = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: The free version does not support VBA automation

Comment: Can you delete the line `Dim oPDF As New PDF_reDirect_v25002.Batch_RC_AXD` and start retyping it from scratch - not copy/pasting? Does the Object for the tool show up in Intellisense as you start typing `PDF_Re`?

Comment: @dbmitch but I've a trail of the pro version

Comment: @dbmitch It shows 'PDF_reDirect_v2500' if I start typing PDF_RE. But still then I get the same error.

Comment: Put in the object that it finds `PDF_reDirect_v2500` if that's what it is - then type the `.` and start typing `Batch` to fill in the last part. You have to use the current version of the object reference.

Comment: @dbmitch it worked! but now I've another problem.    " TempBool = .Utility_Merge_PDF_Files(fld2 & "\" & ofn & " AnotherWord 2014.pdf", Files_to_Merge)  " fld2 gives an error: Method or data member not found

Comment: We typically don't debug programs line for line here. Mark an answer, for the original question, post the next problem code into a new question.  That being said `fld2` is a folder object - not a folder name. It's hard to understand what you're trying to do with the Split and concatenate functions - definitely best to split out your problem code into a new question and explain what you're trying to do with that line

Comment: @dbmitch this is where I found the code: [link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79465/finding-matching-pdf-files-in-different-folders-and-merging-the-two-files-into-o)

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comments this should work assuming your trial Pro version will still allow this feature.

You just have to make sure you're using the correct version of the object that has been registered on your system.

Can you delete the line `Dim oPDF As New PDF_reDirect_v25002.Batch_RC_AXD` and start retyping it from scratch - not copy/pasting? Does the Object for the tool show up in Intellisense as you start typing `PDF_Re`

Put in the object that it finds `PDF_reDirect_v2500` if that's what it is - then type the `.` and start typing `Batch` to fill in the last part. You have to use the current version of the object reference.

Compile your code and see if gets past that line